# How many normalization methods are there and what are they for?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

this [post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/normalize-data) lists 5 types of normalization.

```
Zscore
MinMax
Logistic
LogNormal
TanH
```

is there any other types of normalization that are most commonly used in machine learning?

Answer (score 1):

**StandardScaler**

**RobustScaler** for outliers-heavy dataset(can handle better outliers than other scalers)

to name a few..